# push procedure pop function with sequence number in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to write code for push with procedure and pop with Function .

```
create or replace package pushpop_demo as
procedure push(val varchar2);
function  pop return varchar2;
```

end pushpop_demo;

```
create or replace package body pushpop_demo as
subtype my_string_subtype is varchar2(100);
type varchar2_ntt is table of my_string_subtype;
stuff varchar2_ntt := varchar2_ntt();
procedure push(val varchar2)
is
begin
    stuff.extend;
    stuff(stuff.last) := val;
end push;

function pop return varchar2
is
subtype my_string_subtype  varchar2(100);
begin
    if stuff is not empty then
        val := stuff(stuff.last);
        stuff.delete(stuff.last);
    end if;

    return val;
end pop ;
```

but I get error , my question is how can I do this problem with sequence number ??? or other solution .my code does not run anyway . also I do not want use the package .just with procedure and Function .please help me

Comment: If you do not want to use package then what should be used as a storage for stack?

Comment: Dear @astentx  for your helping , I want to use sequence number instead of stuff to increase the counter and is there no other way to call it besides the package?

Comment: A database sequence (an object) is not intended to be used as a stack, because it advances only in one direction and cannot store any data. You do not need a procedure/function to get next value from the sequence, just use `seqname.nextval`

Comment: @astentx thank you for your help , but I think I could not convey my main question correctly . The code I wrote does not work .what do you suggest  for push and pop .my code does not work .why?

Comment: @fazi - you haven't told us what error you get - just saying it doesn't work isn't very helpful. It isn't clear what you mean about sequences, so please edit your question to clarify the actual problem and what you are trying to do. It would be helpful to include more of the package, particularly where `stuff` is defined, and how you will call the procedure and function.

Comment: At a minimum, your subtype is missing an `is` keyword, but you aren't using that anyway; and you aren't declaring `val`...

Comment: `begin stuff.extend` is invalid statement at least because you didn't declare `stuff`

Comment: @astentx I edit my code. please take a look.

Comment: The see my previous comment. [It works with those two things corrected](https://dbfiddle.uk/EHmqBrcf). So this it really at typo-level... please pay attention to what the compilation errors say.

Answer (score 0):

- You need `/` statement terminators to terminate each PL/SQL block.
- You are missing an `END;` statement at the end of the package body.
- You have not declared the `VAL` variable in the function.
- You do not want to re-declare the `my_string_subtype` type (as it will shadow sub-type declared in the package body).
- You can initialise the collection in the declaration section or an alternative is to initialise it in the `BEGIN ... END` section of the package body.

```sql
create or replace package pushpop_demo as
  procedure push(val varchar2);
  function  pop return varchar2;
end pushpop_demo;
/
```

```sql
create or replace package body pushpop_demo as
  subtype my_string_subtype is varchar2(100);
  type varchar2_ntt is table of my_string_subtype;
  stuff varchar2_ntt; --  := varchar2_ntt();

  procedure push(val varchar2)
  is
  begin
    stuff.extend;
    stuff(stuff.last) := val;
  end push;

  function pop return varchar2
  is
    val my_string_subtype;
  begin
    if stuff is not empty then
        val := stuff(stuff.last);
        stuff.delete(stuff.last);
    end if;
    return val;
  end pop;
BEGIN
 stuff := varchar2_ntt();
END;
/
```

Then you can use:

```sql
BEGIN
  pushpop_demo.push('World');
  pushpop_demo.push('Hello');
END;
/
```

and then:

```sql
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(pushpop_demo.pop());
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(pushpop_demo.pop());
END;
/
```

Outputs:

> ```
> Hello
> World
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/VFP39X_o)